# Listing all nodes created for a time period, Drupal

Tags: drupal, list

I'd like to get/create a list of ALL the nodes created during a time period?
Is there an easy way to do this (w/out creating a custom view and selecting by a time period)?

Is there a module that might already expose this?
I have a large amount of content that will get added to the system every night, and I want to be able to peruse this list; title, url, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not like Views, then your only option is to write a custom module. Need help with it? Just ask where are you stuck.

Comment: Its cool, I can do it. Just was hoping someone already created a node_report (ish) type module.